# In the kinematic equations $\vec{v}^2 = \vec{v}_0^2 + 2\vec{a}\cdot \Delta \vec{x}$, what does squaring a vector mean?

Tags: kinematics, vectors

One of the kinematic equations, $\vec{v}^2 = \vec{v}_0^2 + 2\vec{a}\cdot \Delta \vec{x}$, involves squaring the initial and final velocities. My questions is, if velocity is a vector, what meaning does the squaring have? Does it signify taking a dot product with itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the vector form of the equation about velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76057/)

Comment: When you talk about kinetic energy you are always considering the square of the modulus of the velocity vector or the scalar product of the vector with itself. You can see that they are the same thing.

Comment: $\left . \right .$ yes

Comment: @Roger How did you add a $3$ letter comment? I cannot!

Comment: @Eisenstein Haha I came up with a trick... If you know Latexmath when using \left and \right for big parentheses then you know... ;)

Comment: @StephenG That question has only one answer, and that answer uses calculus. This question has an answer without calculus. Even the calculus-based answer relies on constant $\vec{a}$, so nothing is lost by avoiding calculus, but readability is gained.

Comment: @Eisenstein: Another method to write apparently too short comments is to include a link inside a dot. Like this[.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink)

Answer (score 5):

The vector form of the kinematic equation is

$$ 2\boldsymbol{a}\cdot\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{1}-\boldsymbol{x}_{0}\right) = \boldsymbol{v}_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}_{1}-\boldsymbol{v}_{0}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}_{0} $$ where in **bold** are vector quantities, and $\cdot$ is the dot product.

---

*Proof*

Take the vector form of the change in velocity

$$ \boldsymbol{v}_{1}-\boldsymbol{v}_{0}=\boldsymbol{a}\,\Delta t \tag{1} $$

and change in displacement below. Now any time the expression $\boldsymbol{a}\,\Delta t $ shows up it can be replaced with $(\boldsymbol{v}_{1}-\boldsymbol{v}_{0})$.

$$ \begin{align}\boldsymbol{x}_{1}-\boldsymbol{x}_{0} & =\boldsymbol{v}_{0}\Delta t+\tfrac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{a}\,\left(\Delta t\right)^{2}\\
 & =\boldsymbol{v}_{0}\Delta t+\tfrac{1}{2}\left(\boldsymbol{v}_{1}-\boldsymbol{v}_{0}\right)\,\left(\Delta t\right)\\
 & =\tfrac{1}{2}\left(\boldsymbol{v}_{1}+\boldsymbol{v}_{0}\right)\Delta t
\tag{2} \end{align} $$

The above makes total sense as the displacement vector is proportional to the *average* velocity in vector form.

Now take (2) and multiply both sides with $2\boldsymbol{a}$, and by multiply I mean take the dot product

$$ \begin{align}2\boldsymbol{a}\cdot\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{1}-\boldsymbol{x}_{0}\right) & =\boldsymbol{a}\Delta t\cdot\left(\boldsymbol{v}_{1}+\boldsymbol{v}_{0}\right)\\
 & =\left(\boldsymbol{v}_{1}-\boldsymbol{v}_{0}\right)\cdot\left(\boldsymbol{v}_{1}+\boldsymbol{v}_{0}\right)\\
 & =\boldsymbol{v}_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}_{1}-\boldsymbol{v}_{0}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}_{0} \tag{3}
\end{align}  $$

Comment: I think you meant for the *last* equation in each aligned environment to be labelled as equations $(2)$ and $(3)$, respectively. You can achieve this by changing `\begin{aligned}` to `\begin{align}` (and similar for `\end`) and moving `\tag` within the environment.

Comment: @BrianDrake - yes, but I avoid using the `align` environment as future-proofing as KaTeX does not support it and I think it is the way forwards as it going to replace MathJax soon. Nevertheless, I tried it and it works.

Comment: I do not really know anything about LaTeX except what I copy from examples, so I do not know what the best answer is here. I do know that labelling the correct equation is important, and I find it inconceivable that SE would switch to a renderer that does not allow this.

Comment: @BrianDrake - final note, every line in the aligned environment is technically the same equation as each line starts with $=$, and only substitutions/simplifications happen between lines.

Answer (score 4):

The kinematic equations are scalar equations in general. They only include the magnitudes of vector quantities, not the vectors themselves. They are equations that apply along a bound path or direction given a sign so that the directionality is covered for before applying them.

Otherwise not only the $v$'s but also $a$ and $\Delta x$ ought to have been marked as vectors in your formula.

Comment: -1 As explained here and at the proposed duplicate target, this equation generalises to a vector form just fine. The question has since been edited so $a$ and $\Delta x$ *are* labelled as vectors.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your questions directly:

1. Squaring a vector is meaningless.
2. However, in this case, the equation works if you interpret the squaring as a dot product.

[John Alexiou](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/392/john-alexiou)’s answer gives a [nice proof of this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/626879/279176).